# Artículo definido o indefinido en la pregunta "¿Qué es ___ capibara?"

Tags: artículos, preguntas

Estoy creando un librito para mis estudiantes de primer grado. Quiero empezar con la pregunta "¿Qué es el/un capibara?" ¿Cuál sería mejor? En el  librito uso "el capibara" para describir el animal en términos generales. Por ejemplo: El capibara come plantas. Pero la pregunta me suena rara con el artículo indefinido.

Comment: Quería decir que la pregunta no me suena correcta con el artículo definido.

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar, [capibara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7J868bi) es femenino, así que usaremos los artículos femeninos la/una en lugar de los masculinos.

La RAE dice sobre los artículos determinados que sirven para

> asociar el contenido semántico de este con un **referente concreto**, consabido por los interlocutores: *El cartero ha pasado hoy un poco más tarde*; o con un referente genérico: *El cerdo es un animal doméstico*.

El indeterminado, por contrario

> [uno, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b6iKApr)
>
> 3. art. indet. Indica que lo denotado por el nombre o el grupo nominal al que precede **no designa un individuo particular, sino un tipo**. *Un político debería tener una conducta ejemplar*.

Compara

> Quiero **la** manzana (esa, aquella de la que estábamos hablando)

con

> quiero **una** manzana (cualquiera)

Por tanto, deberías empezar la lección preguntando "Qué es **una** capibara", usando el artículo indeterminado, pues te estás refiriendo al animal como colectivo (esta *especie* de animal).

Después, debes pasar al determinado

> La(s)capibara(s) come(n) plantas

Porque si dijeses "Una(s) capibara(s) come(n) plantas" te podrían preguntar si es que hay *otras* capibaras que comen otra cosa. Una vez que "entras en materia" te estás refiriendo a estos animales como "referente concreto, consabido por los interlocutores" dentro de las especies animales.

De la única manera en que creo que que podrías empezar o titular la lección con "Qué es **la** capibara" es si la hubieses *mencionado previamente*:

> Hoy vamos a estudiar un animal nuevo llamado capibara. Qué es **la** capibara? Pues es un mamífero ...

y aún así suena forzado. Es mejor usar un artículo indefinido al referirse al animal en general.

Answer (score 2):

En español, se pueden usar casi indistintamente el artículo indefinido singular, el artículo definido singular o el artículo definido plural para denotar carácter genérico:

1. Un capibara es un animal.
2. El capibara es un animal.
3. Los capibaras son animales.

Existe, no obstante, una sutil diferencia entre (1) y (2). (1) tiene algo de metalingüístico, como si nos refiriéramos a la palabra más que al animal conocido por ese nombre. (1) tiene algo de: "Usamos la palabra "capibara" para designar a un animal."

Por consiguiente, más que rara la pregunta (a) "¿Qué es un capibara?" parece aludir a un nivel semántico más básico que (b) "¿Qué es el capibara?" Mientras que (a) parece emparentarse con preguntas como "¿A qué nos referimos con la palabra "capibara"? "¿Qué significa "capibara"?", (b) parece dar por sentado que existe un conocimiento básico por parte del que pregunta (por ejemplo, que se trata de un ser vivo) y la pretensión consiste en obtener información adicional.

Mi sugerencia es:

- Si la pregunta aparece en un contexto donde son todos animales, o donde aparecen distintos elementos de un ecosistema, utiliza la pregunta "¿Qué es el capibara?". Respuesta: El capibara es un animal herbívoro que vive en ...
- Si la pregunta aparece en un contexto donde hay muchas palabras difíciles sin ninguna conexión semántica entre ellas, utiliza la pregunta "¿Qué es un capibara?"

Comment: Tu análisis me suena muy coherente. Pero preguntar "¿Qué es el perro?" suena muy mal.